# Covariant derivative on the base space

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

The basic definition of a covariant derivative for a Lie algebra valued n-form $\alpha \in \Omega^n(P)\otimes T_eG$ with $P$ a principle bundle with base space a manifold $M$, and $T_eG$ the Lie algebra of the fiber $G$ is

$$
D\alpha(x_1, ..., x_{n + 1}) = d\alpha(x_1^H, ..., x_{n + 1}^H)
$$

Where $x = (x_1, ..., x_{n+1}) \in T_qP$ and $x^H \in H_qP$, being this the horizontal tangent space at $q \in P$ such that $T_qP = V_qP\oplus H_qP$ and $V_qP \subset T_qG$ the vertical tangent space. Also, $d$ is the exterior derivative map $d: \Omega^n \rightarrow \Omega^{n + 1}$

In Nakahara's "Geometry, Topology and Physics" the equation (10.47) stands that for any Lie algebra valued n-form **defined on $M$**, $\eta$, you can write

$$
D\eta = d\eta + [A, \eta] = d\eta + A\wedge\eta - \eta\wedge A
\tag1$$

Where $A = S_i^*\omega$ with $S_i: U_i\subset M \rightarrow P$ and $\omega$ is the connection 1-form.

I tried to prove it aplying $S_i^*$ to $D\alpha$ since $S_i^*\alpha$ is a Lie algebra valued n-form defined on $M$, after defining $D$ in a more suitable way:

$$
D\alpha = d\alpha + \sum_{i = 1}^n(-1)^{i + 1}\omega(x_i)\wedge \alpha(x_1, ..., \hat{x}_i, ..., x_n)
\tag2$$

Where the hat over $x_i$ means that that vector doesn't appear on $\alpha$

I think this is the right way to define $D$ due to the answer in [Covariant derivative: QFT vs. Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993271/covariant-derivative-qft-vs-math)

But if you apply $S_i^*$ to Eq. (2) and call $\eta = S_i^*\alpha$ you get

$$
D\eta = d\eta + \sum_{i = 1}^n(-1)^{i + 1}(S_i^*\omega(x_i))\wedge (S_i^*\alpha(x_1, ..., \hat{x}_i, ..., x_n)) = \\ d\eta + \sum_{i = 1}^n(-1)^{i + 1}A(x_i)\wedge \eta(x_1, ..., \hat{x}_i, ..., x_n)
$$

Therefore, Eq. (2) is equal to Eq. (1) only in the case $\eta \in \Omega^1(M)\otimes T_eG$, i.e. just for $n = 1$. Nevertheless, Nakahara ensures that is true for any n.

Is Eq. (2) wrong or maybe my interpretation of commutator in Eq. (1)? How can you write in terms of a connection 1-form the covariant derivative for any Lie algebra valued n-form such that when defining on $M$ (i.e., after using $S_i^*$) leads you to Eq. (1)?

Answer (score 1):

Eq(2) is problematic. Firstly, you omitted the pushfoward of the representation which is important. The correct formula is $$D\alpha=d\alpha+\rho_*A\wedge\alpha.$$ Secondly, in the answer you quote, the formula $$\rho_*A\wedge\omega(X_0,\dots,X_k)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\rho_*A(X_i)\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X_i},\dots,X_k)$$ is just unwinding the definition of exterior product in terms of alternating multilinear function. You cannot compare the form (which is a function) with the value of function.

In the case of matrix Lie group and adjoint representation, the map $\rho:G\to \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ is just given by $\rho(g)(X)=gXg^{-1}$, thus the Lie bracket comes out as you push forward the representation at identity, so that $\rho_*(A)(B)=[A,B]=AB-BA$.

As a result, in your notation, $$D\alpha=d\alpha+\rho_*\omega\wedge\alpha=d\alpha+\omega\wedge\alpha-\alpha\wedge \omega,$$ thus $$S_i^*(D\alpha)=dS_i^*\alpha+S_i^*\omega\wedge S_i^*\alpha-S_i^*\alpha\wedge S_i^*\omega=d\eta+[A,\eta]$$

Comment: My problems: 1) I don't understand why you need $\rho_*$ in $D$, between which tangent spaces acts?; 2) why $\rho_*(A)(B) = [A, B]$?

Comment: 1) It is the formula indicated in the answer you quote, in "Covariant derivative: QFT vs. Math". If you are asking how to derive $D\alpha=d\alpha+\rho_*\omega\wedge\alpha$ from $D\alpha(...)=d\alpha(pr_h...)$, you can see for example section 2.2.2 of this link : https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/Lect2.pdf. To generalize the argument to $V$-valued $k$-forms, you can work locally and use Leibniz rule. 
2) Let $g(t)$ be a curve in $G$ with $g(0)=I, g'(0)=A$. $\rho_*(A)(B)=\dfrac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(\rho(g(t))B)=\dfrac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}gBg^{-1}=g'(0)B-Bg'(0)=AB-BA$.